# Get all windows of length 3 from bigquery array

Tags: google-bigquery

If I had a table like:

```
value1 | value2 | value3
-------|--------|-------
  a    |   1    |.  z
  a    |   2    |.  x
  a.   |.  3    |.  z
  a.   |.  4    |.  x
  b.   |.  1    |.  x
  b.   |.  2    |.  z
  c.   |.  1    |.  z
  c.   |.  2    |.  x
  c.   |.  3    |.  z
```

And I wanted to get all the ordered windows of three values from this, such as:

```
(a, [(1, z), (2, x), (3, z)]), (a, [(2, z), (3, z), (4, x)]), (c, [(1, z), (2, x), (3, z)])
```

using BigQuery, how would I do this in an aggregation across multiple unique value1 keys and ensure they're ordered by value2.

So my query would be something like:

```
SELECT
    val1,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value2, value3)) vals
FROM my_table
```

And then I would need a query to window over this to get all the groupings of three values.  I assume I could use ROW_NUMBER() or something, but I'm not sure if there's a simple way to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standrad SQL

Version 1:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  value1, [arr[OFFSET(pos)], arr[OFFSET(pos + 1)], arr[OFFSET(pos + 2)]] arr
FROM (
  SELECT value1, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value2, value3)) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY value1
  HAVING ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) > 2
), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) - 3)) pos
```

Version 2:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  value1, ARRAY(SELECT s FROM UNNEST(arr) s WITH OFFSET ord WHERE ord >= pos ORDER BY ord LIMIT 3) arr
FROM (
  SELECT value1, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(value2, value3)) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY value1
  HAVING ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) > 2
), UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) - 3)) pos
```

If to apply both versions to dummy data from your question using below CTE

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' value1, 1 value2, 'z' value3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 2, 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 3, 'z' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 4, 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 1, 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 2, 'z' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 1, 'z' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 2, 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 3, 'z' 
)
```

result is

```
Row value1  arr.value2  arr.value3   
1   a       1           z    
            2           x    
            3           z    
2   a       2           x    
            3           z    
            4           x    
3   c       1           z    
            2           x    
            3           z
```

Obviously, you can package output in whatever way you need